# How to recover a possibly corrupted Eclipse project?

Tags: eclipse, web, project, recovery, corrupt

Whenever I try to open a file in the project I'm working on I receive this error:

```
Operation failed. File system input or output error
```

The error details are:

```
Message reported from file system: 250 OK. Current directory is /
```

When I have previously received similar errors, simply restarting Eclipse was enough to resolve them. I don't think my workplace is corrupt because I can open files from one of my other projects fine.

What could be causing this error? If my Eclipse project is corrupted, what is the best practice for fixing it?

Answer (score 0):

I went in to the RemoteSystemsTempFiles folder and renamed the temp files directory for the website. This solved the problem. Something must have corrupted inside that folder.